# Jquery Automatically Convert Text to HREF Link in Blog Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Running into an issue. In running the code below, I'm trying to replace a string of text that appears in an blog excerpt field with a clickable link.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('post-excerpt');
    if (elements.length > 0) {
    
    $('.post-excerpt').html($('.post-excerpt').html().replace(/((http:|https:)[^\s]+[\w])/g,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>'));
    }
    
});
```

The problem is that the link from the first except is being copied to all other buttons on the page. How do I modify the code above to make sure that it parses through each excerpt link UNIQUELY and replaces that string with an equivalent HTML link?

[image: Blog page]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the first captured string `$1` in the newValue param, use the variable which holds your link from the post.

```js
var link="https://foo2.pdf";

$(document).ready(function() {


$('.jet-content-fields__item-supplies-pdf .jet-content-fields__item-value').html($('.jet-content-fields__item-supplies-pdf .jet-content-fields__item-value').html().replace(/((http:|https:)[^\s]+[\w])/g, 
'<a href="'+link+'" target="_blank">'+link+'</a>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jet-content-fields__item jet-content-fields__item-supplies-pdf">
<div class="jet-content-fields__item-value">
   https://foo.pdf
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I can't explicitly assign the PDF link to a variable, since it's going to be different on different pages, so I can't use "link" in the code.